# Why can't use npm run build to execute webpack command in window?

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack

`Nodejs: v16.15.1`, `NPM: v8.11.0`, `Webpack: v3.12.0`, `Webpack-cli: v3.3.6`

In package.json, I declare script: `"buildlib": "webpack --config lib-bundle.js"`, `"build": "npm run buildlib && webpack --watch --config webpack.dev.js --progress --display-error-details"`.

Firstly, when I open terminal and run `npm run buildlib` or `npm run build`, nothing works without any errors. But I can use `webpack --config lib-bundle.js` and `webpack --watch --config webpack.dev.js --progress --display-error-details` to build my project.

Secondly, after building the project, I create two files `new.js`, `new.jsx` and copy content from existing files `event.js`, `event.jsx` for them (just rename class name).

After that, I re-run `webpack --config lib-bundle.js` and `webpack --watch --config webpack.dev.js --progress --display-error-details` and realize that only existing files from the first build can accept changes without errors. All new files created after the first build receive an error: `You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type`

How to fix this?

Run npm
[image]

Run webpack (not first time):
[image]

Comment: I fixed my first issue by removing `webpack.js` from the root folder. This file is used for build on production but I don't know why it creates issues on development. @@